# Windows 7 detects USB drive, but not HID devices (mouse & keyboard)

Tags: windows-7, usb, keyboard, mouse, hid

I'm encountering a weird issue with my Windows 7 x64. Suddenly (I don't know since when) my USB port is not recognizing any HID devices such as mouse, keyboard and card reader. But plugging in USB flash drives and external HDD works absolutely fine.

I don't see how it could be a driver issue since the devices are plug and play, and  other ports work fine.

Update: devices doesn't work before POST too.. What's interesting is I can't boot into my Live USB with that port. It simply doesn't detect. Only when I get to the OS (Ubuntu/Windows) that the USB drive is detected

Comment: I know you said other ports work fine, but have you tried moving your mouse/keyboard/card reader to different ports? I would say try uninstalling and reinstalling your drivers but that might be difficult without any kind of input... do you know at what point they don't work? are you able to get into BIOS? or are their no lights on any of your devices the entire boot sequence?

Comment: @mael' The devices work fine on other ports. I booted into Live Ubuntu, and same case. That one port recognizes USB storage, but not HID devices. Wtf is going on? If it's damaged, why does my flashdrive works fine with it??

Comment: That is strange that it's the same deal on Ubuntu - that rules out any kind of weird group/local policy setting. Do these USB storage devices have independent power supplies? or are they also powered by USB?

Comment: No, they're regular flash drives and external HDDs, no external power supply.

Comment: so your HID devices all work before POST then?

Comment: Drivers for HID devices and USB flash drives are quite different. I bet something was happened with them.

Comment: @mael' HID devices doesn't work before POST too.. What's interesting is I can't boot into my Live USB with that port. It simply doesn't detect. Only when I get to the OS (Ubuntu/Windows) that the USB drive is detected.